# How to use differentiation in a function in Sage

Tags: symbolic-math, sage, differentiation

I am trying to create a function that take a function as input that return a tuple with the function and its derivative.
In all my attempt the derivative of the function is evaluated to zero or one even if it is a symbolic function:
I simplified the code to return only its derivative:

```
t = var("t")
q = function("q")(t)

print("Expected",diff(q,t))  # return diff(q(t), t) as expected

Gamma(a) = diff(a)
print("Unexpected_v1 ",Gamma(q))  # return 1

Gamma(a) = diff(a,a.arguments()[0]) 
print("Unexpected_v2 ", Gamma(q)) # return 1

Gamma(a,b) = diff(a,b)
print("Unexpected_v3 ", Gamma(q,t)) # return 0
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve.  But at any rate your line

```
Gamma(a) = diff(a)
```

is kind of dangerous, because this is not legal Python (`a` is not defined).  What happens is that Sage "preparses" it:

```
sage: preparse('Gamma(a) = diff(a)')
'__tmp__=var("a"); Gamma = symbolic_expression(diff(a)).function(a)'
```

So you can see that `a` is now a symbolic variable, and so it has a default variable `a`, so the derivative will obviously be `1`, and you have assigned `Gamma(a)` to always return this.  The other ones will behave analogously.

If you are sure your input will always be correct, you should `https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLSU1T8K10K81L1kjTtOLlUgCCotSS0qI8hTSdlMy0NKAwLxcvV4mCrUJZYpGGUokSkF8I5KUB9ZRk5udpKBUqaWqUAEWh5hRqAgD_FBee&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==`.

```
def MyFunc(f):
    return f,diff(f)

t = var("t")
q = function("q")(t)
MyFunc(q)
```

This is super generic, though, so it might be too much so for your purposes.  Hopefully it points you in the right direction.